# d3 scaling basic shapes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to dynamically scale some shapes based on the data. Here's what I have so far:

```
svg.selectAll(".point")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "point")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"))
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + 
    y(d.y) + ")"; });
```

Is there another attr that I can add? I tried to use the following but not working:

```
.attr("transform", "scale(xMap)");
```

xMap is a value in data scaled to a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the `translate` and the `scale` in the same anonymous function. Besides that, you have to concatenate the string with the number. The way you're doing...

```
"scale(xMap)"
```

... you're passing literally "xMap" to the `scale()`.

Thus, it should be:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ") scale(" + xMap + ")";
});
```